# Loading a random class using reflection and have it register as a component in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a random class in a random package that is loaded through reflection after the app launches, is there a way for it to be registered as a component under springboot and have annotations such as `@Autowired` and `@Value` etc work for that class.

It works when it is in the same package at launch time, but if introduce it thorough another jar at runtime (same package or not) it doesn't work.

Below are samples that don't work even if it is in the same jar. I can't change the app's configuration - it would defeat the "random package/random class" objective.

Code in Spring boot application package

```
package sample.app
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Code that starts app
        //
        //
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            Class test = Class.forName("test.Test", true, Application.class.getClassLoader());
            System.out.println(test.getMethod("getName").invoke(null));     //NPE
            System.out.println(test.getMethod("getProfiles").invoke(null)); //NPE
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;

@DependsOn("blaaaaaaaah")
@ComponentScan
public class Test {

    @DependsOn("blaaaaaaaah")
    public static String getName() {
        return SpringGetter.instance.getApplicationName();
    }

    @DependsOn("blaaaaaaaah")
    public static String[] getProfiles() {
        String[] profiles = SpringGetter.instance.getEnv().getActiveProfiles();
        if (profiles == null || profiles.length == 0) {
            profiles = SpringGetter.instance.getEnv().getDefaultProfiles();
        }
        return profiles;
    }

}
```

SpringGetter.java

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component("blaaaaaaaah")
public class SpringGetter implements InitializingBean {
    public static SpringGetter instance;

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private  String applicationName;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public SpringGetter() {
        System.out.println("consASFJEFWEFJWDNFWJVNJSBVJWNCJWBVJNVJNVJSNJSNCSDJVNSVJtruct");
    }

    public String getApplicationName() {
        return applicationName;
    }

    public void setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
    }

    public Environment getEnv() {
        return env;
    }

    public void setEnv(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setInstance() {
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
I managed to dynamically create the SpringGetter class as part of the same package as the Application class(the one with the `@SpringBootApplication`). I got Test.java to point to that dynamic class and yet no luck.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you're trying to do, or why you have to do it after the app has started rather than as part of the application starting. You might be able to use `org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.scan(String...)` for your purposes.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson An example I can give on the top of my head, that might satisfy such a scenario. A Java agent attaches during runtime, and requires one of its classes to be registered as a component to either get the application context or just about anything else.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I tried using that class you shared, but no luck in getting anything about the application that is running within that process, I did manage to get my class instantiated though. app name was set to "${spring.application.name}" and env was just a default object for that class

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "getting anything about the application that is running within that process". Perhaps you could provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) that shows what you're trying to do in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

To simply inject fields into a POJO as if it were a Spring-managed bean, you can use something like the following:

```java
@Component
public class BeanInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
  }

  public void initializeObject(Object pojo) {
      beanFactory.autowireBean(pojo);
  }
}
```

**Note**, however, that this *only* injects fields marked as `@Autowired` or `@Injected`. It does *not* create proxies that honor method interception strategies based on e.g. `@Transactional`, `@Async`, etc.

Comment: where is this BeanInitializer class declared and defined? I can't change/add anything related to the app.

Comment: `BeanInitializer` is a bean that you would use to 'initialize' your POJOs, e.g. during retrieval from a Repository (in which case it would be declared in your repository and used prior to returning your POJO). If you cannot change the existing application code *at all*, you will need to use AspectJ and compile-time/load-time weaving. See these two projects as an inspiration: https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-source-weaving-example https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-loadtime-weaving-example

Comment: I can get the classes loaded after application start, using the same classloader as the application - show in the question. All I need is a way for the class to be registered as a component dynamically to the springboot app that started up. I really don't want to change application code. Sort of like a hook in the framework

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring 5, have a look at the [registerBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#registerBean-java.lang.Class-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionCustomizer...-)() method from GenericApplicationContext. You can find an example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-beans

The issue in your Test class may also be that you're not loading the Spring Boot context from the main class. You can use the SpringBootTest annotation for this.